# Counting <LI> elements from another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two pages, page A and page B.  Page A will hold an unknown number of unordered list elements.  I wont have any control on how many list elements there are.

On Page B, I'd like to use PHP to grab the number of li from Page A and display that number.  The idea is Page A will hold Wordpress post links that a user has favorited, while Page B will display that amount of favorites.

Any help would be wonderful.  Thanks

Comment: If both pages are part of the same WordPress install, it would probably be easier to get the number of favorited links from the database instead of trying to parse page A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse html from another page using **[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**. [Download it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/latest/download?source=files) and include to your script:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/yourpage.php');
$licount = count($html->find('li')); // Here it is
```

Okay. Looks like OP don't need to use serverside code. Use javascript for this (don't forget to include jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("/favorites", function(data){
        $("#favorites").html($("li", $(data)).length)
    })
})
```

This will replace content of element `#favorites` with number of `li`s in /favorites file

Comment: I've been trying to get this working... but with no luck... I copy it directly to my page, wrap it with php, and my page comes up blank.  I've copied the simple_html_dom.php file into the same directory as the file I've included the script in.  The page just comes up blank.

Comment: I fixed it, there was a ';' missing after the include.  Another problem though is... I am including a page, url.com/favorites, and after echoing the $licount, it's returning '1'.  I have around 5 LI's on the page.  When i change the echo to $html, I can see only 1 li, and it's sayings I am not logged in.  I am working on wordpress.

Comment: Also, thank you so far for the help.  If you are unable to help further, I understand.

Comment: Can you post example of `url.com/favorites`?

Comment: well it's unordered list is generated by the user.  when they add posts to the favorites it's displayed in a list format on the favorites page.  <ul id="favorites"><li>link</li><li>link</li></ul>

Comment: Looks like your `/favorites` page has only one li. Are sure there are more?

Comment: If i go to the page with my browser, i can see 5.  I can add many more if needed.  When I change the echo to $html, it says there are no favorites, and I need to login to add some.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15547/discussion-between-daniil-and-ryan)